# Web2py Google App Engine Testing

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I'm building an GAE app with web2py and am struggling with setting up a test framework.
I've looked into:

- **web2py_utils**
- **nosegae**
- Googler Ikai Lan's [suggestions](http://ikaisays.com/2011/02/19/unit-testing-in-tipfy-an-app-engine-framework-in-python/)
- [gaetestbed](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html) which was merged into GAE apis

Here's a unit test I attempted:

```
import unittest
import nose
from nose.tools import *
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_itil

class UserModelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # First, create an instance of the Testbed class.
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        # Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
        self.testbed.activate()
        # Initialize the datastore stub with this policy.
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)

        self.env = new_env(app='fb', controller='default')
        self.db = copy_db(self.env, db_name='db', db_link='sqlite:memory')

        self.user = self.db.auth_user.insert(first_name='Bob', last_name='Narley', fb_id=1, password='testtest')
        self.dream = self.db.dream.insert(title='Graduate UC Santa Cruz with Computer Science degree by June 8, 2012.',
        type='education', owner = self.user, progress=92.0)
        self.task1 = self.db.task.insert(dream=self.dream, title='Buy batteries for calculator', solution='Go to Walmart at 12:00pm October 30, 2012 and buy Duracell AAA.',
        status=1)
        self.task2 = self.db.task.insert(dream=self.dream, title='Make Winston happy',
                       solution='Make banana milk',
                       status=0)
        self.user.update_record(tasks=[self.task1, self.task2])

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def test_create_user(self):
        assert_equal('Bob', self.user.first_name)
        assert_equal(1, self.user.fb_id)
        assert_equal('testtest', self.user.password)

    def test_user_has_many_tasks(self):
        tasks = self.db(self.db.task.id.belongs(self.user.tasks)).select()
        assert_equal(2, len(tasks))
```

**run_fb_tests.py:**

```
from web2py_utils.test_runner import run
import sys

run(path = sys.path[0],
    app = 'fb',
    test_key = 'superSecret',
    test_options = {'verbosity': 3, 'with-gae': True, 'without-sandbox': True},
    coverage_report = 'logs/coverage_report.txt',
    DO_COVER = True,
    DO_NOSE = True,)
```

I get the following error when execute my run_fb_tests.py

**ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext**

I've been banging my head for days now with many errors. This is only one of many

## **How do you setup a testing framework in web2py for GAE apps?**

Comment: +1 I'd be interested since I chose web2py for one deployment http://joeyonlinecorner.appspot.com and now for instance we want to add something like a wiki or a blog but I couldn't get any web2py plugin to work with GAE even though the web2py author spcifically said the tested at least one plugin with GAE. If you post to the google web2py groups the authors may read your question and answer.

Comment: What do you see when you put `print sys.path` before calling `run()`? Is google.appengine on that path? There doesn't seem to be anything in the code that specifically excludes it, so I'm wondering if the script is just not aware of where your App Engine packages are.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your script run_fb_tests.py? If it is in the web2py folder I get a similar error, but if you place it in google_appenine, or in the containing folder of the google_appengine then I get no import errors.